# Get To/CC/BCC addresses from a MimeMessage?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to get the To/CC/BCC addresses from a JavaMail `MimeMessage` object. It seems that the only way I can do this is through `getRecepients`, but then I can't tell who's in the `To` field vs the `CC` and `BCC` fields. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> getRecipients
>
> public Address[] getRecipients(Message.RecipientType type)
>                           throws MessagingException
>
> ```
> Returns the recepients specified by the type. The mapping between the type and the corresponding RFC 822 header is as follows:
>
>                 Message.RecipientType.TO                "To"
>                 Message.RecipientType.CC                "Cc"
>                 Message.RecipientType.BCC               "Bcc"
>                 MimeMessage.RecipientType.NEWSGROUPS    "Newsgroups"
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Note that you'll never find Bcc recipients on a message you **receive**, that's the whole point of "Bcc".

Comment: I did not downvote... you're correct when it comes to the client, but we do not know in which position of the chain the OP wants to examine the message.

Comment: Right, we don't know, but people are sometimes confused by this so I thought it was worth pointing out.  Maybe someone else can upvote it if you agree it's information worth pointing out?

Answer (score 3):

[`MimeMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) does have the method [`getRecipients()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getRecipients%28javax.mail.Message.RecipientType%29) which has an input parameter of type [`Message.RecipientType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.RecipientType.html). Just use that...

Answer (score 0):

I have answer to your question, which is working for me.

Message msg = folder.getMessages(1);
 Address[] a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);